# Power BI visualizations - categorized stacked boxes

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image: Power BI visual attached]

I'm new to MS Power BI & looking to create a visualization report which looks like the image. The data is coming from SharePoint Lists & will have to be categorized. Under each category, there will be items (more than 1). Also looking to see if a status bar % complete can be added to each of the boxes based on a scale of 1-100.

Comment: Can you please draw, even by hand, even in Paint, what do your desired results look like?

Comment: the desired results image is included in the submission.